# Annotation Clustering Breaks when using UIViewRepresentable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a MKMapView that is being handled with a SwiftUI `UIViewRepresentable`. The problem is that my clustering is failing to work as expected. My code produces the following series of problems.

- Map loads, clusterable annotations cluster as expected.
- Zooming in on a cluster de-clusters them.
- Zooming out, they re-cluster, however if I zoom out even further, additional annotions are not clusterd with the group.
- Zooming back in after encountering this bug, results in no more clustering of any kind.

#### Cluster Annotation View

```swift
final class ClusterLocationAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
        static let identifier = "cluster-location-annotation-identifier"

        // Omitted irrelevant `UILabel` and other views. 
        
        override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            displayPriority = .defaultHigh
            collisionMode = .rectangle
            clusteringIdentifier = "location-detail-cluster-id"
            canShowCallout = false
            setupUI()
        }
        
        // Removed Required Init
        
        private func setupUI() {
            addSubview(backgroundView)
            addSubview(label)
            addSubview(offersLabel)
            
            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerXAnchor),
                label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerYAnchor)
            ])
            
            offersLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                offersLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: 4), // adjust the constant as needed
                offersLabel.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerXAnchor)
            ])
        }
        
        // MARK: - Configure Cluster
        func configure(appConfig: AppConfig, clusterLocations: [LocationDetail]) {
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(cgColor: appConfig.secondaryColor.cgColor ?? UIColor.black.cgColor)
            backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = appConfig.globalCornerRadii
            
            label.text = clusterLocations.count.description
            label.textColor = UIColor(cgColor: appConfig.secondaryColor.contrastingColor().cgColor ?? UIColor.white.cgColor)
            
            // Set number of locationDetails that contain an offer, to the text, eg. offersLabel.text = locationsWithOffersCount
            var offerCount = 0
            
            for location in clusterLocations {
                offerCount += appConfig.hasOffer(for: location) ? 1 : 0
            }
            
            offersLabel.text = "\(offerCount) Offer(s) Available"
        }
```

#### Annotation View

```swift
    final class LocationAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {
        static let identifier = "location-annotation-identifier"

        // Removed irrelevant views.
        
        override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
            super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            displayPriority = .defaultHigh
            collisionMode = .rectangle
            clusteringIdentifier = "location-detail-cluster-id"
            canShowCallout = true
            setupUI()
        }
        
        //Removed Required INIT
        
        private func setupUI() {
            addSubview(backgroundView)
            addSubview(imageView)
            addSubview(label)

            backgroundView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                backgroundView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
                backgroundView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
                backgroundView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40),
                backgroundView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40)
            ])

            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerXAnchor),
                imageView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerYAnchor),
                imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
                imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30)
            ])

            label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.bottomAnchor, constant: 4),
                label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: backgroundView.centerXAnchor)
            ])
        }

        func configure(with location: LocationDetail, and category: Category, appConfig: AppConfig) {
            backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor(cgColor: appConfig.secondaryColor.cgColor ?? UIColor.black.cgColor)
            backgroundView.layer.cornerRadius = appConfig.globalCornerRadii
            
            imageView.image = Iconoir.uiImage(from: category.iconName)?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
            imageView.tintColor = UIColor(cgColor: appConfig.secondaryColor.contrastingColor().cgColor ?? UIColor.white.cgColor)
            
            self.label.text = location.locationName
        }
    }
```

#### Coordinator MKMapViewDelegate Functions

```swift
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, clusterAnnotationForMemberAnnotations memberAnnotations: [MKAnnotation]) -> MKClusterAnnotation {
            return MKClusterAnnotation(memberAnnotations: memberAnnotations)
        }
        
        func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            let appConfig = parent.appConfig
            
            if let cluster = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation {
                let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: ClusterLocationAnnotationView.identifier, for: cluster) as? ClusterLocationAnnotationView
                annotationView?.frame.size.height = 40
                annotationView?.frame.size.width = 40
                annotationView?.configure(appConfig: appConfig, clusterLocations: cluster.memberAnnotations as! [LocationDetail])
                return annotationView
            } else if let location = annotation as? LocationDetail {
                let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: LocationAnnotationView.identifier, for: annotation) as? LocationAnnotationView
                annotationView?.frame.size.height = 40
                annotationView?.frame.size.width = 40
                let category = appConfig.category(from: location.categoryId)
                annotationView?.configure(with: location, and: category, appConfig: appConfig)
                return annotationView
            }
            
            return nil
        }
```

#### Update UIView

```swift
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        let coordinator = context.coordinator
        mapView.mapType = mapType
        mapView.userTrackingMode = trackingMode
        handleLocationChange(mapView, coordinator: coordinator)
    }
    
    func handleLocationChange(_ mapView: MKMapView, coordinator: Coordinator) {
        if coordinator.lastLocations.count != locations.count {
            mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
            mapView.addAnnotations(locations)
            mapView.setRegion(getRegion(for: locations), animated: true)
            
            coordinator.lastLocations = locations
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                trackingMode = .none
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues needed to be resolved. Firstly, I subclassed `MKMapView` on my `Coordinator`, I don't think this is truly needed as I have access to the `mapView` instance in `updateUIView`.

I needed to update my `makeUIView` to properly update based on the updated state. Previously, I was mishandling my `@State` and both updating `@State` from the `makeUIView` and from the `UIViewRepresentable` struct. The general rule here is that any value that is update from `UIViewRepresentable`, aka a `State` value is published from SwiftUI, it should update the value on the `Coordinator`. Any value that the `Coordinator` updates, should be published to the `State` variable in the `UIViewRepresentable` struct. That will in turn, cause the `updateUIView(..)` function to be called, updating the `Coordinator`'s property value with the newly updated `State` value.

```swift
    func updateUIView(_ mapView: MKMapView, context: Context) {
        mapView.mapType = mapType
        mapView.userTrackingMode = trackingMode
        mapView.removeAnnotations(mapView.annotations)
        mapView.addAnnotations(locations)
    }
```

To solve the `MKAnnotation` clustering issue I checked my code for the `clusteringIdentifier` and I had a `clusteringIdentifier` on my `LocationDetail` as well as set on `LocationAnnotationView` and on my `ClusterLocationAnnotationView` so I removed that value and am only using it when the `viewForAnnotation(:)` is called.

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
            let appConfig = parent.appConfig
            
            if let cluster = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation {
                let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: ClusterLocationAnnotationView.identifier, for: cluster) as? ClusterLocationAnnotationView
                annotationView?.frame.size.height = 40
                annotationView?.frame.size.width = 40
                annotationView?.configure(appConfig: appConfig, clusterLocations: cluster.memberAnnotations as! [LocationDetail])
                annotationView?.clusteringIdentifier = "clustering-location-detail-identifier"
                return annotationView
            } else if let location = annotation as? LocationDetail {
                let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: LocationAnnotationView.identifier, for: annotation) as? LocationAnnotationView
                annotationView?.frame.size.height = 40
                annotationView?.frame.size.width = 40
                let category = appConfig.category(from: location.categoryId)
                annotationView?.configure(with: location, and: category, appConfig: appConfig)
                annotationView?.clusteringIdentifier = "clustering-location-detail-identifier"
                return annotationView
            }
            
            return nil
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

handleLocationChange needs to be moved into the coordinator so it can be called in the map region changed event.

Also perhaps remove the location count check, it looks error prone.

Comment: Yeh so I dreamt on it last night. Can I ask, I think I'm using my `updateUIView` incorrectly in this instance, where I'm tying my `self` for the representable, directly to the `Coordinator` class. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I should instead have a copy of each of the "Binding" variables, for example `isInteracting` on the Coordinator, rather than accessing the binding values from within the coordinator. For example, if SwiftUI publishes an update, it should then update the non binding value of the coordinator, however the coordinator should update the binding values, and never itself?

Comment: You can set the bindings on the coordinator in `updateUIView`. But since binding is a pair of get/set closures and you only need a set, you can instead set a new closure and call the binding setter within it. Also you should set the closure nil before you update the map to prevent an update loop, then set a new closure that uses the latest value of the binding.

Comment: I bet you are currently passing a binding to the Coordinator's init which is a common mistake because it is only called once so will be out of date when the representable struct is re-init in the parent View's body.